# Is there an elegant way to traverse Clang AST Statements?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++

I am trying to traverse all function definitions and extract information from them. I have to iterate over all statements in the function body, and depending on the type, execute a specific function.

For the moment I have an ugly if-else block. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
void FunctionMatcher::processStatement(const clang::Stmt *statement) {
    string type = statement->getStmtClassName();
    if (type == "ReturnStmt") {
        auto rs = dyn_cast<const ReturnStmt *>(statement);
        processReturnStmt(rs);
    } else if (type == "WhileStmt") {
        auto ws = dyn_cast<WhileStmt>(statement);
        processWhileStmt(ws);
    } else if (type == "ForStmt") {
        auto fs = dyn_cast<const ForStmt *>(statement);
        processForStmt(fs);
    } else if (type == "IfStmt") {
        auto is = dyn_cast<const IfStmt *>(statement);
        processIfStmt(is);
    } else if (type == "SwitchStmt") {
        auto ss = dyn_cast<const SwitchStmt *>(statement);
        processSwitchStmt(ss);
    } else if (type == "CompoundStmt") {
        auto cs = dyn_cast<const CompoundStmt *>(statement);
        for (auto child : cs->children())
            processStatement(child);
    } else {
      // ...
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html

Comment: @KostasRim Thats what I use to extract the functions. Now I want to iterate over the statements in the body and process them.

Comment: Looks like the classic use-case for a [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), no?

Comment: @G.M. I would need to extend the Stmt classes with the accept method, no? Those are library classes.

Answer (score 1):

By navigating through the code of clang::TextNodeDumper, I found a solution.
Apparently Clang has its own visitors for statements, declarations etc...
Simple example:

```
class StatementVisitor : public ConstStmtVisitor<StatementVisitor> {

public:
    StatementVisitor();

    void Visit(const Stmt *Node) {
        ConstStmtVisitor<StatementVisitor>::Visit(Node);
    }

    void VisitIfStmt(const IfStmt *Node) {
        llvm::outs() << " An if statement yay!\n";
    }

    void VisitWhileStmt(const WhileStmt *Node) {
        llvm::outs() << " A While statement yay!\n";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [RecursiveASTVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html)

its traverse all statement in given code, recursively

```
class MyASTVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<MyASTVisitor>
{
    public:
    bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl* f)
    {
        ...
    }

    bool VisitIfStmt(IfStmt* IF)
    {
        ...
    }

    bool VisitForStmt(ForStmt* FS)
    {
        ...
    }

    bool VisitWhileStmt(WhileStmt* WS)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```